# ASSERT_EQ with boolean failing in gtest

Tags: c++, boolean, googletest

I have an custom aggregate template type that I am trying to test using gtest. I am using a TYPED_TEST_P, and testing various types. It works fine until I try to do boolean types. I get the following "error"

```
error: Value of: const_img.at(pt.x,pt.y)
  Actual: true
Expected: *buffer
Which is: true
```

So this is saying there is an error: true != true. Anyone see this problem before? How do you fix it?

I can't post all of the code here, but:

The call that catches the non-error is:

`ASSERT_EQ(*buffer,const_img.at(pt.x,pt.y))`

`TypeParam` is a typedef for `bool` in this case, provided by Google Test based on `TYPED_TEST_P`.   `buffer` has the following type:

```
const TypeParam* buffer;
```

`const_image` is a `const Image<TypeParam>&` (custom class), which forces `at` to be the const overload, with the footprint:

```
const TypeParam& at(ptrdiff_t col,ptrdiff_t row) const;
```

Obviosly, this is returning the correct value (true should equal true), and a breakpoint on the following if statement is never reached:

```
  if (*buffer != const_img.at(pt.x,pt.y))
  {
    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
  }
```

If I skip testing the const overload, I get no errors (which is weird).

Edit: Work Around

The following work around works, but is...dumb.

```
  TypeParam a = const_img.at(pt.x,pt.y);
  TypeParam b = *buffer;
  ASSERT_EQ(
    a,b);
```

Comment: Care to show us the line of code that's causing the problem?

Comment: @KerrekSB Hopefully, what I've added is enough context to answer the question...

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258230/passing-a-typename-and-string-to-parameterized-test-using-google-test

Comment: Can you show the signatures for `operator==()` and `operator!=()`. The expectation is that there is a single version for each and it acts on `const` objects, and `operator!=()` is implemented in terms of `operator==()` (or the other way round).

Comment: Sorry, pixel_t is just `typedef TypeParam pixel_T`, i forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible your values are being converted to `int` somewhere within the expansion of the `ASSERT_EQ` macro?

What if you try the following, to ensure the values of `*buffer` and `at(..)` are treated as `bool`?  It sounds like `bool` is the only type parameter for which this problem arises.

```
ASSERT_EQ(static_cast<TypeParam>(*buffer),
          static_cast<TypeParam>(const_img.at(pt.x,pt.y)));
```

This concern arises from looking at the following signature within Google Test v 1.7 (`gtest.cc`, line 1114):

```
// The helper function for {ASSERT|EXPECT}_EQ with int or enum
// arguments.
AssertionResult CmpHelperEQ(const char* expected_expression,
                            const char* actual_expression,
                            BiggestInt expected,
                            BiggestInt actual) {
// ...
```

EDIT:

If you want this to just work, you should be able to use the following:

```
#include <functional>  // std::equal_to
//  ...
EXPECT_PRED2(std::equal_to<Pixel_t>(), *buffer, const_img.at(pt.x,pt.y));
```

This will apply the arity-2 comparison functor.  Google Test will also print your individual arguments and their values in the event of failure, so you don't lose functionality.

Unfortunately, this answer doesn't explain what's happening in your original problem.  I tried observing this problem myself, which would make troubleshooting a lot easier, but didn't see it with a minimal test case using Apple LLVM 5.0 and Gtest 1.6.

Comment: Hmmm, now that I re-read this, I wonder if my edit and answer are correct.  You say that the TYPED_TEST_P case is `bool`, but do you mean `TypeParam` _is_ `bool`, or is the case: `TypeParam` is `pixel_T<bool>`?  If the latter, we need to revert my edit and follow up on Senti Bachcha's question of `operator==` for `pixel_T`

Comment: Sorry about the delay in answering, there was a family emergency. pixel_T is just a typedef (typedef TypeParam pixel_T). Static cast makes `UnitTestImage.cpp(327): error: Value of: static_cast<pixel_T>(*buffer)
  Actual: true
Expected: static_cast<pixel_T>(const_img.at(pt.x,pt.y))
Which is: true`

Answer (score 2):

{EXPECT_EQ(, )} internally cast bool to int or some other numeric type. The c++ standard says that bool when is false is represented as 0, but when is true is represented by something other number than 0. Which means that in your case:
{EXPECT_EQ(true, true)} 
may internally be evalueated as:
{EXPECT_EQ(4, 1)}
And this comparation fails.